# identify the predicate and verb phrase

Tags: verbs, phrases, predicate

Identify the predicate and verb phrase - "Women should wear long sleeves and long dresses or trousers, so their body is covered."

Comment: Hello Helen, and welcome to ELL. On this site, people asking questions have to show that they have tried to answer the question themselves already, so please [edit] this question to tell us what you know about verb phrases and predicates, what you think the answer is, and why you're unsure. Also, each question should be about a particular aspect of learning English. This is just a homework question.